# plt.close('all') Python not working in Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, spyder

I have been trying to close all graphs at the beginning of my code in Spyder using Python, however I did not come up with a solution.
I have searched several ways to do it, however none worked, included the coded especified by matplotlib.
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(3)
plt.close('all')
```

I am wondering if it is a Spyder bug.

Does anybody have a clue of what can i try to do?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution mentioned here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5350
and i tried the one you described, but it didn't work for me either.

I guess it would be the best to use the shortcut "ctrl+shift+w" before executing your code.